# Is there a plugin to show outline of rst in vim

Tags: vim, restructuredtext

Is there a way to show outline of rst files in vim?
That could let me jump to section faster.

I would like it provide function like nerdtree.
It would better to show on another separate window.

Or, if there any method to fold RST file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try [Voom](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2657). It is stable and works perfectly with reST and several other formats. I also use it to see outline of my Python scripts.

Comment: I like voom more then dotoutlineree.

Answer (score 2):

There is [DotOutlineTree](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1225). I have had good experiences with it.

Comment: It still buggy.  When I try to move following section, it failed. 

    =====
    Sec.1
    =====

It can only handle one line section markers.

Comment: @DanielYCLin Have you tried [VOoM](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2657), it works pretty well for me although I'm not an intense rst user.

Comment: @nye17, You should post another answer, I found VOom work perfectly.

Comment: @DanielYCLin ;-) that's fine, people would find out through the comment, and you could upvote the comment as well.

Comment: @nye17 Really, you should post an answer. It'll stand out better.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using tagbar together with rst2ctags

and the following settings in my _vimrc (gVim) or in my init.vim (NeoVim):

```
" ReStructuredText support in tagbar
let g:tagbar_type_ReStructuredText = {
  \ 'ctagstype': 'rst',
  \ 'ctagsbin' : 'rst2ctags.exe',
  \ 'ctagsargs' : '-f - --sort=yes',
  \ 'kinds' : [
    \ 's:sections',
    \ 'i:images'
  \ ],
  \ 'sro' : '|',
  \ 'kind2scope' : {
    \ 's' : 'section',
  \ },
  \ 'sort': 0,
\ }
```